# Can't open file attachment with Libreoffice snap

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, thunderbird, snap

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and have Libreoffice 6.2 installed as a snap app. I'm trying to open an attachment from Thunderbird, but get the following error message

[image]

I can save the file to my Downloads directory and then open it, but would like to open it straight from Thunderbird without having to save it. I've looked at trying to give Libreoffice access to the `/tmp` directory but can't find any way to do that. Any other suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: Same problem here with both opening from Thunderbird and Firefox (attachment/download). So far I found files written to /tmp/ have read-only credentials and no other, but for some reason, LibreOffice cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the reason seems to be that the instant application is like freeoffice
(try "snap list" in a console to see them)
freeoffice 6.2.4.2 120 canonical stable - -

can not go to parent directories as if they did not have privileges.

However I gave full rights for the whithin directories to anybody..

Only solution I found is to move considerated files in directories that you can reach from "Open File menu"